# multiprocessing.Process isn't opening multiple drivers and scraping them at the same time

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, multiprocessing

I'm trying to open up multiple webpages using selenium in Python and interact with the pages at the same time using different accounts but it only starts a2 after completing a1. Why isn't it running both functions at once so I can interact with the website using multiple accounts at the same time?

```
def function1(url,email,password):
 driver = webdriver.Chrome
 driver.get(website url)
 # LOG IN 

def function2(url,email,password):
 driver = webdriver.Chrome
 driver.get(website url)
 # LOG IN USING DIFFERENT ACCOUNT

a1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function1(url,email,password))
a2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function2(url,email, password))
a1.join()
a2.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function in the process:

```
Process(target=function1(url,email,password))
```

`function1(url,email,password)` returns None

So you are actually calling:

```
Process(target = None)
```

How to use multiprocessing.

```
a1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function1, args=[url, email, password])
a2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function2, args=[url, email, password])
a1.start()
a2.start()
a1.join()
a2.join()
```

I would also suggest reading a bit more about it in here:
https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing.html